# Pine-Script: Multiple Timeframe Loss Streak Stop

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading

I'm trading hourly chart and would like to stop after 2 consecutive losses, only for the current day.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you share your code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.